# How to take power of each element in a matrix in Netlogo?

Tags: matrix, netlogo

I would like to take all elements of a matrix to the power of a specific number.
I have a matrix using the matrix extension set up like this:

```
let A matrix:make-constant 4 4 5
```

which gives a 4x4 matrix with values of 5 in there

Now I want to take all elements in the matrix to the same power, so say I want to take them to power 2, then I want to end up with a 4x4 matrix with numbers 25.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple ways. The simplest is probably with `matrix:times-element-wise`. Unfortunately, this will only work for integer powers greater than or equal to 1:

```
to-report matrix-power [ mat n ]
  repeat n - 1 [
    set mat matrix:times-element-wise mat mat
  ]
  report mat
end
```

You can also convert the matrix to a list of lists, and then use map on that to raise each element to a power. This has the advantage of working with 0, fractional powers, and negative:

```
to-report matrix-power [ mat n ]
  report matrix:from-row-list map [ map [ ? ^ n ] ? ] matrix:to-row-list mat
end
```

`map [ ? ^ n ] some-list` raises each element of a list to the power of `n`. `matrix:to-row-list` converts the matrix to a list of lists. So, we apply `map [ ? ^ n ]` each list in the result of `matrix:to-row-list`. Then, we convert the result back into a matrix with `matrix:from-row-list`.

You can generalize this to do any element-wise operation:

```
to-report matrix-map [ function mat ]
  report matrix:from-row-list map [ map function ? ] matrix:to-row-list mat
end
```

Then, we could define the power function as:

```
to-report matrix-power [ mat n ]
  report matrix-map task [ ? ^ n ] mat
end
```

Comment: Cool use of tasks. If tasks had existed when the matrix extension was written, perhaps `matrix:map` would have been included in the extension. Note that matrices are mutable, so the choice exists of whether to construct a new matrix for the result (as you did), or whether to mutate the contents in-place.

Comment: The extension could even just use a command block, right? Anyway, opened a feature request for it: https://github.com/NetLogo/Matrix-Extension/issues/2

Comment: Good point, the extension could have used a reporter block for this, even before we had first-class tasks.